# Typescript function to mute HTML audio

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, audio

I have audio that auto-plays on screen load. I am trying to include a button that will mute the audio using Typescript. The app is built in Angular4. I have tried using

```
document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
e = e || window.event;
audio.muted = !audio.muted;
e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

but am getting `Event is not assigned to MouseEvent`, it also says `muted` does not exist on type `HTMLElement`.

Is there a way to do this in the `main.ts` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `muted` property is present on the `HTMLMediaElement` interface. You have to use type assertion to assert that `audio` is of type `HTMLMediaElement` type.

```
let audio = document.getElementById('your-audio-element') as HTMLMediaElement
// ...
audio.muted = true;
```